# Is it possible to alter and read messages in iMessage via an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, imessage-extension

I have an idea for an iMessage app, but it requires the following:

- ability to read the current user message and replace the text (specifically only when the app is clicked in the iMessage toolkit)
- ability to add an additional option for user to click when a message is held down (where the current options are "reply, copy, translate, more ...")
- ability to temporarily replace the text of that corresponding held down message, similar to how the "translate" function does

Is all this something that is available to a developer with the iOS toolchain? How can this be done, programmatically?